# ! Missing $ inserted: error when using simple array

Tags: errors

I am new to latex. I am getting `! Missing $ inserted` error when I am trying to create an array of two columns.

code:

```
\vspace{0.5in}
\begin{array}{cc}
Name of Candidate} & Signature\\
\end{array}
\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \large\item\textbf{name 1}
    \large\item\textbf{name 2}
    \large\item\textbf{name 3}
    \large\item\textbf{name 4}
  \end{enumerate}
  
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: `array` has to be used in math mode. Use  `tabular`  instead.

Comment: okkk I did use Table and  thank you  very much for the information

Comment: unrelated but only the first `\large` does anything there, it applies to all the items. It would be better to move it just before the `\begin{enumerate}`